# Objective C: same value of objects of custom class

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have UserViewController to display user's info and friends. Let's say there is a variable (NSString) called userName. 
Through navigation controller user can go from his profile (UserViewController) to a profile of another user (same UserViewController) and go back to own page. So when he comes back userName is not his own name, but the name of the user he just visited a profile of.

Why this variable acts like this - like it is common for all objects of same class?

**EDIT:**

```
// UserProfileViewController.h

@interface UserProfileViewController ()
@end

@implementation UserProfileViewController

PFUser *user_user;
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote?

Comment: It depends upon how you declared the variable. We cannot help you without seeing how this variable was declared.

Comment: Another strange thing happening in project is that "same-name" variables in different controllers cause error.

Comment: @Rob 
This seems to work:

interface UserProfileViewController ()
{
private PFUser *user_user;
}
end

Comment: Yep, that's why I asked. Just sitting in `@implementation` without braces makes it a global. If you put it in braces (and better, put it in `@interface`), makes it an instance variable.

Comment: As Rob says, it is a static or global variable (depending where exactly it is positioned). When it is global and you do the same within another class using the same variable name, then the linker will run into errors complaining about duplicate symbols (or so).

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot. Now it works good. So thats why I get compile error if I have variables with same names in different viewcontrollers?

Comment: @MikhailChesnokov Yep, accidentally using globals like that would cause those sorts of linker errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initial code posting the`PFUser` reference you are using is a **global** variable, and therefore its state is not tied to any one particular instance of `UserProfileViewController`.

It looks like in the comments you have figured it out but just to be clear you need to declare it as an ivar or a property to make it tied to an instance of `UserProfileViewController`:

```
@interface UserProfileViewController()
{
    PFUser *user_user;
}
@end
```